# Numbered buffers

Tags: buffers

I think when I was using Vim buffers were numbered and very easy to switch
between (`4gt` etc.?).  Is there nothing like this in Emacs?
With ido and
an evil leader binding, `<space>bn<cr>` (if name.org is the only file beginning in n) is slightly worse.

Comment: With `ido` you should be able to switch between buffers without having to complete buffer names with `TAB`.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10, you're right.  edited.

Comment: The order of the `buffer-list` gets updated continuously as you switch between buffers (most recent buffers move to the front of the list).  Although you could write some code to assign a permanent number to each buffer, in this case, you might be better off getting used to the Emacs conception of buffer numbering, *especially* if you leave a session running for a long time and accumulate more than a few buffers.  (I say this as former Vim user.)